# Android when activity loses focus and is brought back by notification, sound will no longer play

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I have a timer running and at various points play short audio clips(dings or voices) all less than 4 seconds.  This is one if statement in the timer that can play a sound:

```
Random rand = new Random();
if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0) {
    restSoundsH[rand.nextInt(rests.length)].start();
} else {
    restSoundsT[rand.nextInt(rests.length)].start();
}
```

The restSounds are a private array loaded in the onCreate method and have 4-12 sounds each:

```
            restSoundsH = new MediaPlayer[rests.length];
            restSoundsT = new MediaPlayer[rests.length];
            for(int i = 0;i < rests.length;i++){
                restSoundsH[i] = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(rests[i] + "h", "raw", getPackageName()));
                restSoundsT[i] = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(rests[i] + "t", "raw", getPackageName()));
            }
```

When the activity is created I create a notification like this:

```
//create notification
        Intent intent = getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName())
                .setPackage(null)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel =
                    new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Main Channel");
            notificationChannel.setSound(null,null);
            nm.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentText("Remaining: ")
                .setContentInfo("Info")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

The notification is updated every second.
I want the app to run even when it loses focus(home button etc) or phone is slept which it does.

The problem is, when it loses focus and the notification is clicked on or the phone is slept and then brought back the sound no longer works. Its strange in the fact that only certain sounds at first. If I cancel the activity and start it again no sounds work. It is almost like it is certain Media arrays that get blocked.

EDIT: This only happens on actual phones(tested on 3 different), works fine on emulators.

What am I doing wrong. Let me know if you need to see other code.

Thanks

Comment: So I believe the issue is that I am creating around 50 MediaPlayer objects instead of recycling a few.  I have read posts that say creating to many causes issues. Since my clips are short I switched to SoundPool and solved the issue

Answer (score 4):

```
new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
```

You are creating a notification channel with importance of "IMPORTANCE_LOW".

No sound will be played when the channel set to "IMPORTANCE_LOW".

Try to initialize the channel with "IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT" or higher importance.

for more details, please check the android developer documents.
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance

Comment: The reason I did this was to stop the notification sound.   The sound works fine until focus is changed. I do not believe the notification has anything to do with the activity playing sound does it?

Comment: ohh. I`m sorry that I misunderstood what you mean.Really sorry.